# SQLite vs HSQLDB

Tags: sqlite, hsqldb

What are the main differences between **SQLite** and **HSQLDB**? There are lots of applications using both of them, but I don't really see any major difference.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

SQLite is implemented in C, HSQL is implemented in Java.

It should be more seamless and easy to integrate SQLite with an application project written in C or C++, whereas I would expect the HSQL technology is easier to integrate with a project written in Java.

No doubt there are numerous other more subtle differences between these two embedded databases, but the above is the most prominent difference.

Comment: Yet [SQLite appears to be the default database for Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html) - why's that?

Comment: @dwjohnston, I don't know, you'd have to ask Google.

Comment: @dwjohnston My guess is, that's because only Android's SDK is in Java, but the underlying linux and even parts of the userland are still in C. Besides, in general, C gives better performance than Java, hence `sqlite` and not `hsql` in android apps by default.

Comment: "Besides, in general, C gives better performance than Java" - citation needed.

Comment: Java was inefficient in its earliest versions, but that hasn't been true since the 1990's. There might be a few specific tasks for which C has better performance. Java sometimes suffers "stop the world" effects during garbage collection, whereas in C you have to take care of memory yourself.

Comment: C is basically an assembly language, which makes it a lot faster than a partly interpreted language like Java

Comment: @TomDoodler, C is not assembly language.

Comment: @Christian Brüggemann, since java is garbage collected, it is slower than C because we have to do manual memory management.

Comment: @ChristianBrüggemann C is *way* faster than Java. here's your citation: https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/gpp-java.html

Comment: sqlite is the "universal db", it is present in every linux/unix  distribution, macos, and of course android, and also presents in windows ( it was present also in the dead windows phone!). Thus, it is present in Android  because it is present everywhere.

Answer (score 28):

The good comparison of HSQLDB & SQLite can be found at http://3rdstage.blogspot.com/2009/03/comparion-of-hsqldb-h2-sqlite.html

Answer (score 5):

IMHO *THE* biggest difference is, that SQLite has no user management at all in contrast to HSQLDB.

(This does not want to say anything bad about SQLite. SQlite defenitely has its usecases it is also very widely used.)